# Error during replicate on postgres SQL DB

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to implement a PostgreSQL replication for  application. 
My primary to secondary replication is working fine, however if I failover to secondary the replication is not working..

I keep seeing below error in every replication attempt.

Timestamp for replication test is: <20180201154242>
Getting secondary timestamp before primary update ===> Command: <"C:\Program Files\BMC Software\Control-M Server\pgsql\bin\psql" -w -t -Upostgres -dpostgres -hCTM-S -p5433 -c"select 'CurrentTimestamp:' || VALUE || ':CurrentTimestamp' from DBU_REPLIC where NAME='timestamp_ctm'"> failed

Can I please have some guidance.

Comment: Is this configured in cluster?

Comment: That command isn't coming from Postgres. It's coming from some third-party software. You should probably ask whoever wrote it.